# audio amplifier design

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, design

I have been assigned a task to design an adjustable audio amplifier. the circuit should be able to tune into the edge frequencies fl and fh as well as A1, and A2 as seen in the attached file below. Furthermore, it is anticipated that I need to design various filters for different frequency bands ( eg. high pass filter for f ≥ fh).

A

Comment: Check out the good old Baxandall tone correction circuit.

Comment: Looks like you'll need a high pass and low pass filter...

Comment: Useful search terms : shelving lowpass filter, tone control. I don't see any reason to use discretes here, unless you're not allowed to use an opamp.

Comment: What level is your background ? student or technician ? You will need to define your target process more clearly. Are you designing a "Shelving Filter" ? Is the PassBand basically flat from Lo to Hi ? What shape factor do you require for the HiPass and LoPass slopes ? Do you require a HiFiAudio Bessel or can you use a Butterworth form ? Bauxendahl may fit your possible requirements, but has neither of the bandpass forms I have suggested. Are you required to use a "single stage" circuit or can you use a LoPass stage combined with a HiPass stage ?

Comment: The text by Walter Jung is a "cook-book" of workable designs, 
mostly based on OpAmps.  

I can direct you to my own very specific study of audio filters 
based on the Multiple-FeedBack BandPass OpAmp approach. 
[Linear IC Design Applications](http://www.geocities.ws/glene77is/).

Comment: I am currently a student. Figure 2 pretty much shows what I need to achieve . thank you.

Comment: @laptop2d It looks like a -40db/dec, so a single 2nd order stage shelf filter would do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this DC-coupled diffpair, with filtering between the collectors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTFGfA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the block diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7fsKJ.png)</sup>

Here is the frequency response you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmjUuL.png)</sup>

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time and replying. I was just wondering if you can show me the block diagram of the above circuit.

Comment: Also, can you provide me a detail operation of the circuit please.

Comment: If you need to reject 50Hz tone from the power supply, replace the long-tail diff-pair current-source (R3) with a real current source. And add cascodes (shields against Early Effect) to *ALL* the transistors. With biasing for those 6 additional transistors.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I have made the block diagram of what i think i should do for the design. but there seems to be something wrong in it. the block diagram i have is " amplify input signal -> Low pass filter -> high pass filter - power amplification - speaker. But when i showed this to my lecturer he said the filters i used in that manner is wrong. So, I was thinking instead of using low pass filter and high pass filter in series do you think i should just use butterworth low pass filter. thank you

Comment: Also, in the design requirement it says that i need to use a high pass filter for when the frequency is higher than hf. but im confuse here, like if i use a high pass filter above hf, then that will block the low freq. while passing high freq. Its probably something simple and im just over complicating it. can you plz help

Comment: The sharp filtering you requested ---- 15:1 rolloff in just 2 octaves ---- requires 2 poles and 2 zeros. The discrete circuit I gave you does that behavior. You will need to adjust C1 & R6, and adjust C2 & R11, to those poles and zeros.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

it is fairly easy to design an opamp that roles off at fl at a pre-set gain / octave -> it is a low-pass filter.

you will then need to design a high pass filter that kicks in at fh at the same pre-set gain / octave so the gain is flat after fh.

it is much easier to work with an opamp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, we can't we cant use op-amps only bjt

Comment: Hey, my lecturer has changed his mind and now allows us to use op amps. So, how would i design the high pass filter to make it flat after fh

Answer (score 0):

Especially since the filter specs will change, you should do this digitally.  There are plenty of DSPs that compute a few low pass and high pass filters at audio sample rates.

Let's say you sample at 50 kHz, which is one sample every 20 µs.  Even something running at 50 MHz instruction rate can do 1000 instructions per sample.  That's plenty to several low and high pass filters.

Comment: One of the restraints of this task is that we can't use any digital electronics. thanks your response tho.

Comment: @Swa: Then you should state that requirement in your question.  You also need to justify why that requirement exists, else it sounds like something you made up because you just don't want to use digital for religious reasons.